# How to delete a specific record (fixed length) includes data from a .txt file?

Tags: c#, file, record

I am new in C# and I am making project but I can't make this delete part ..

If I save my data in .txt file in one line, but contain many fixed length record with no delimiter, if each record has fixed length and each field has fixed length and saved in file like this

```
1ahly2zamalek
```

how do I delete, for example the record `2zamalek` from line with entering to the program id=2?

```
public team()
        {
            Team_ID_Len = 5;
            Team_Name_Len = 10;
            Team_Rec_Len = 15; ;

            Team_ID = new char[Team_ID_Len];
            Team_Name = new char[Team_Name_Len];
        }
```

Comment: What's this string comprised of such as [id][name][teamId][teamName]? why are you not using a delimiter?

Comment: no its a line in text file contain 2 same records in 1 line [team_id][team_name][team_id][team_name]

Comment: no delimiters cause its a project and it ordered no delimiters

Comment: Your number is the delimiter. What uniquely identifies the beginning of each record other than the id?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for `Substring`. Give it a start (length of record * how many), and the length (length of record).

Actually, you might want to create the string as `string s = part1+part2` where `part1` is the substring from 0 till the start of the record, and `part2` is the start of the NEXT record, until the end.

Then just save it.

Comment: save it back ? not sure what's your question with this what next.

Answer (score 0):

Your number is your delimiter, [split with a char array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

using System;

```
using System;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string words = "1sdklfjlsdf2lksjdf3sfd4sfd5fsd6fsd7fsd8fsd9sfd10aslkdfj11jklh12hjk";
        int deleteRecordId = 11;
        string [] split = words.Split(new Char [] {'1', '2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'});

        string newString = "";
        int j = 0;
        for( int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
        {

            if ( j == deleteRecordId)
            {
             //ignore this record
             Console.WriteLine("ignore i = " + i);
                j++;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("i = " + i);
                if(!( split[i] == ""))
                {
                    newString += j +  split[i];
                    j++;
                }
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine(newString);
    }


}
```

then WriteAll to the file

Comment: aha i see thanks man i am trying to do now and anything i will till you in comment here ... thanks again.

Comment: If this is the answer to your question please mark it off

Comment: what happens when he has 10 records ?

Comment: @Noctis good point see [update](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EvGq5M) also int i was being incremented twice

Comment: the null string will be added and an inappropriate increment. [alternatively](https://dotnetfiddle.net/E87u35)

Comment: had a look at the last link. id's aren't saved properly (1 become 0, and so on), it's a bit messy, and it'll ignore numbers higher than 10.

Comment: @Noctis ok with a slight [modification](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1Oz8Y7) testing 11

Comment: you still have a record with 0 in the start, you obviously care about this more than the person who asked the question, and without the OP actually caring or commenting, I don't see much point in this :)

Comment: @Noctis Thanks for the feedback. Time to move on :)